# Connect to Android device using WiFi Direct

Tags: pi-3, android, wifi-direct

I would like to connect my Raspberry Pi 3B to a WiFi Direct group created on my Android phone. After enabling WiFi with `raspi-config`, I started `wpa_supplicant` with the following command:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/p2p.conf -B
```

The file used in the above command is as follows:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
ap_scan=1
device_name=Raspberry-Pi
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
```

After starting `wpa_supplicant`, I started `wpa_cli`:

```
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
Interactive mode
>
```

Next, I was able to discover my phone as a peer with `p2p_find`:

```
> p2p_find
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
...
<3>P2P-DEVICE-FOUND 82:58:f8:c7:e2:81 p2p_dev_addr=82:58:f8:c7:e2:81   pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='XT1635-01_9d83' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0 new=1
```

However, when I attempt to connect with the push button option using `p2p_connect`, the result is always immediately `FAIL`:

```
> p2p_connect 82:58:f8:c7:e2:8 pbc join
FAIL
```

Before attempting to connect, I made sure the Android phone is listed as a P2P peer.

According to [this documentation](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README-P2P):

> "join" indicates that this is a command to join an existing group as a
>   client. It skips the GO Negotiation part. This will send a Provision
>   Discovery Request message to the target GO before associating for WPS
>   provisioning.

Since I want the Raspberry Pi to be a client (i.e. not the group owner), this seems like the correct option to me. Before executing the `p2p_connect` command above, I selected "Start PBC" on my Android device under the WiFi Direct settings.

Am I following the correct procedure to connect? If possible, I would like to connect by sending an invitation that can then be accepted on the Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I discovered the problem. The WiFi Direct group created on my Android device defaults to a channel on the 5 GHz band which is not supported by the Raspberry Pi. I used an Android app to change the channel to a suitable 2.4 GHz channel. After doing so, I was able to join the existing WiFi Direct group with the same process outlined in the question:

```
> p2p_connect 82:58:f8:c7:e2:81 pbc join
```

I also did not need to select the "Start PBC" option on my Android device. The `p2p_connect` command issues an "invitation to connect" pop-up instead.